# Usual causes for bad preprocessor warning

Tags: fortran, fortran90, intel-fortran

I am unfamiliar with what causes the following warning:

```
warning #5117: Bad # preprocessor line
#include "rtt_alloc_rad.interface"
```

I've looked at the obvious problems such as the `#include` is flushed left. I would love to get some tips for where to look for possible causes.

I'm using an Intel compiler: ifort version 15.0.1

The code is with a large climate model linked to an external library.
It is difficult to know what to post, but the warning comes from the following snippet:

```
MODULE rtt_interface

use rtt_types,    only : rtt_options, rtt_coefs, profile_Type, &
transmission_Type, radiance_Type,rtt_coef_scatt_ir,rtt_optpar_ir, &       
rtt_chanprof, rtt_emissivity, rtt_reflectance
use rtt_const,    only : errorstatus_success, errorstatus_fatal, & 
platform_name,inst_name
use rtt_unix_env, only : rtt_exit
use cosp_kinds,     only : wp,wi,wl

IMPLICIT NONE

real(wp), parameter :: tmin_baran = 193.1571_wp  

#include "rtt_alloc_rad.interface" 
#include "rtt_alloc_transmission.interface"
#include "rtt_alloc_prof.interface"
#include "rtt_dealloc_coefs.interface"
#include "rtt_direct.interface"
#include "rtt_print_opts.interface"

! snip...

END MODULE rtt_interface
```

I compile with the flags: `f90flags=-g -fp-model precise -traceback -r8 -O0`

Comment: It helps if you show the code

Comment: Does it help adding `-fpp` to your compile flags?

Comment: @francescalus Yes, adding -fpp does help. What was wrong and how did    -fpp help?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The message

> warning #5117: Bad # preprocessor line

is potentially a little misleading.  It suggests that the code has been passed through the preprocessor and it's the preprocessor that's unhappy.  That isn't always the case: ifort also produces this warning message when preprocessor directives occur in the source file but the preprocessor isn't invoked.

To ensure that the preprocessor is run you have a couple of options:

- add the flag `-fpp` (or `-cpp`) to the compilation command;
- name the free-form source file with the suffix `.F90` (note the capital).

Comment: I understand. Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: In Visual Studio: Open right-click on the project and select Properties. Then set `Fortran`/`Preprocessor`/`Preprocess Source` File to `Yes (/fpp)`. Pay attention to select the correct Configuration and Platform. I normally select this option for All Configurations and All Platforms

Comment: Alternatively, preceding the preprocessor definitions with `!DEC$` should tell the Intel Fortran compiler to call the preprocessor. So, `#if (var.eq.1)` becomes `!DEC$ if (var.eq.1)`.